# Assembly Language in Dos Debug

Tags: assembly, dos

How to see the value of AL Register. *(AX=AH+AL)*
I have changed the value of Ax register.

```
AX 0000
:100
-r
AX=0100  BX=0000  CX=0000  DX=0000  SP=FFEE  BP=0000  SI=0000  DI=0000
DS=0B38  ES=0B38  SS=0B38  CS=0B38  IP=0100   NV UP EI PL NZ NA PO NC
0B38:0100 B80100        MOV     AX,0001
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem here? You have already indicated that you know that AX is made up of theAH and AL registers and you can see AX.

Comment: I want to see the value of AL register

Comment: I don't think this is a real question.

Comment: Practice following commands
1. Debug (enter the program)
2. Q  (Quit from program)
3. R  (To see contents of all registers)
4. R <register> (To see specific register contents + option to change its value).
see the contents of AX register and try changing its values to 1, 21, 321, 4321, 54321,GF
5. Try to see value of AL (AX=AH+AL)

Comment: I am asking the Last Question

Comment: two last digits of AX = AL

Comment: @AlexanderZhak are you sure ?

Comment: Yes, when in hex notation. The two bytes that make up the register AX can be accessed as registers AH and AL. So when AX=1234h, AH=12h and AL=34h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is AX modulo 256. In the hexadecimal output, it is the two leftmost digits (00) in your case, that is why hexadecimal output is so practical in assembly.

Comment: Thank You .! seva already answered that but i'am accepting your answer too . :)